# connecting Android app to external database

Tags: android, mysql

I've always heard about how you need to do 'tunneling' or php+json to access an external database from android apps, which seems very complex to me.

today I've read an article/tutorial explaining how to connect the android app directly to an external database (in this case mySQL), just using INTERNET permission and JDBC.

if this is true, what would be the point on using php+json?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using php+json?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of using direct connection with java+JDBC?

Comment: Security. In order to do a direct connection to the DB, you need credentials. In your APK, those credentials can be exposed, which would be very, very bad. Using PHP would allow you to only expose what you want to return, based on whatever information it receives; this way the client never actually touches the DB and it's -more- secure. So, just because you CAN do something, doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea.

Comment: ok, thanks! so I guess I better start learning some PHP and JSON... any nice tutorials on this?

Comment: Very welcome. And I hate recommending w3schools, but you can probably get enough just from there to build everything you need: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: And apart from php+json, is there an even more secure way to connect to the database?

Comment: Security is being pretty loosely defined here, but in this case I think you're referring to, it's probably one of the best and easiest ways to ensure your DB is 'secure'.